# Как обьеденить два цикла Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно объеденить два цикла для получения двух переменных, из двух разных источников для того чтобы запихать в одну комманду добавления в столбец данных. Как это можно реализовать?

```
    @commands.command()
async def hel(self, ctx):
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="\ Список команд")

    db_1 = data_helpcmd["music"]["desc_music"]
    db_2 = data_helpcmd["music"]["cmds_music"]

    for command in db_2.splitlines():
        for description in db_1.splitlines():
            embed.add_field(name=command, value = description)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

я использую toml, в файле что то на подобии

```
[music]
cmds_music = """
!example_text ...
!example text ...




[music_desc]
desc_music = """
!example_text ...
!example text ...
```

Comment: если у вас это массивы равной длины не нужно таких сложных конструкций

Comment: поправка, объедИнить

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас это массивы равной длины не нужно таких сложных конструкций, можно сделать так:

```
commands = data_helpcmd["music"]["desc_music"].splitlines()
descriptions = data_helpcmd["music"]["cmds_music"].splitlines()
size = len(commands)
for i in range(size):
   embed.add_field(name=commands[i], value = descriptions[i])
```

Но если честно, то формат хранения не очень удобен в `toml` можно иначе:

```
[music]
example_text1 = {"desc" = "example_desc1"}
example_text2 = {"desc" = "example_desc2"}
```

И читать это так:

```
import tomli

with open("file.toml", mode="rb") as fp:
  config = tomli.load(fp)

for music_name, music_info in config['music'].items():
  print(music_name, music_info['desc'])
```

Вывод:

```
example_text1 example_desc1
example_text2 example_desc2
```

В `music_info` в последующем можно будет добавлять и другие характеристики.